# How to hide "Add Media" from frontend users?

Tags: wordpress, media

I'm running a multi author's wordpress site, and users can post contents directly from the front end of my site.

My problem is this, file upload is directly allowed on the front end of my wordpress site.

I want a situation whereby, when users click on Add Media button from my site post submission form,

[image]

Instead of seeing this wordpress Add Media Library to select and upload media,

[image]

I want them to see this instead. Takes them straight to their device file.

[image]

Any code i can use to execute this on my wordpress site?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want to get help, your question should follow some rules.Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then do some research for related topics here or in oter sites. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, preferably with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

To hide “Add Media” from frontend users, you should limit access to the media library to administrator and editor roles only.

From [WP Beginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-media-library-access-to-users-own-uploads-in-wordpress/), You’ll need to add the following code to your WordPress functions.php file or a site-specific plugin.

```
// Limit media library access

add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'wpb_show_current_user_attachments' );

function wpb_show_current_user_attachments( $query ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $user_id && !current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts
') ) {
        $query['author'] = $user_id;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

This code uses `current_user_can` function to check if the user has the capability to activate plugins or edit other user’s posts. If they don’t, then it changes the query used to display media files and limit it to user’s ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will this code, send users to select pictures directly from device?.

Comment: Also, i don't intent to disable that functionality, but i just don't want users to see that wordpress Add Media Library, rather i want them to see the option to select photos from their device...

Comment: This code only hide medias from the wordpress Library to all users but administrators. However it won't sent users to select pictures directly from device. It will allow them to pick media from their device or from their **own** media library. The same process as usual but no visibility on others users libraries.

Comment: i want users not to see that wordpress media dashboard. rather they select and upload images from their own phone media gallery. Any code i can use to achieve this results.

Comment: Please i still need help with this?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question, you should probably delete this one and ask another, following @pgk comment's recommendations on jan'30.